# Когда скрываю меню, оно сначала дергается влево, а потом скрывается. Как пофиксить?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Понял, что это из-за появления скролл-бара. Но как пофиксить, придумать не могу.
https://codepen.io/Anton-forntend/pen/zaRbYq/`введите сюда код`

Comment: в каком браузере это наблюдается ?

Comment: По ссылке перейди и сам поймешь. Это не баг в браузере

Comment: я посмотрел - и не увидел того что вы написали

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно задавать координаты меню от левой стороны экрана. Но задавать нужно явно в пикселях, а это значение мы можем получить только скриптом.

```
mainMenu.style.left = document.body.clientWidth + 'px';
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeoPOL